# knockout accessing a parent observable in child function

Tags: knockout.js

in knockout given a viewmodel

```
 function Model() {
     var self = this;
     this.mycollection = ko.observableArray("")
     this.foo = ko.observable("foo");
     ....
  }
```

in the observable array how do I access the parent?

```
 function mycollection (bar){
           var self = this;
           this.bar = ko.observable(bar);
           this.myFunction = function() {
              var foo = $parent.foo();
              ...
              }
           }
```

is it self.$parent.foo? 
or do I need to pass it in somehow when I call the function?

```
 <div class="modal-body" data-bind="foreach: selectedFilteredPoCollection">
    ....
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                                   data-bind=" click:  myFunction($parent.foo()) </button>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your click handler in a function, like so:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        data-bind=" click: 
             function(){ 
                 myFunction($parent.foo());
             }"> </button>
```

See Note 2 here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Comment: Yep that worked (I'll mark it answered as soon as it lets me. Just to be clear the child does not have access to the parent?  so for instance if I was doing a ko.computed function in the child I could not reference stuff in the parent?

Comment: not sure what you're asking. are you asking if you have access to the parent data from within myFunction? only if you pass it in.

Comment: I am asking in mycollection   mycomputed=ko.computed(function () { return $parent.foo() + this.bar() },this);

Comment: you've got a variable declaration and a function declaration for mycollection, so as is, nothing is really wired up correctly. You can access parent data by scoping correctly, such as with a `self` object

Answer (score 2):

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to your click function.

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($parent, $parent.foo)"></button>
```